# Getting Image/File Data From WebKitFormBoundary Django Python

Tags: python, django

`request.POST['name']` does not work, But `request.body` will show all `WebKitFormBoundary`. I want to keep a single variable.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary0n4xFpxTSpVthuKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
------WebKitFormBoundary0n4xFpxTSpVthuKP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="address"
```

Comment: How are you POSTing this data? Where is it coming from?

Comment: from Angularjs .

 $scope.httpfunction = function(){
            var allform = new FormData($("#myform")[0]);
               
  $http({

        url: "/test/",
        method: "POST",
        data: allform ,
                    header:{'Content-Type':undefined},

        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.responsedata = data

            //$scope.show = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here


        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;

        });

Comment: it seems I have the same problem. The request.POST is empty and request.body seems to contain the form elements.
I submit my form with JavaScript Fetch and FormData() as I need to send files too. However I cannot even get the text data with out even trying to send the files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use request.FILES['image_file_name_here'] to access the individual file. So for example if you wanted to save the file that you sent you could do:

```
with open('image.png', 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in request.FILES['image_file_name_here'].chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```